# How to resolve "Premature end of data in tag schema line 2"

Tags: validation, xsd, xml-parsing

I'm writing an XML schema but am getting the following error when I save the file in Notepad++

"XML Parsing error at line 791
Premature end of data in tag schema line 2"

I can see that people have had similar issues in the past with "Premature end of data in tag  line X" but none of them seem to be resolved. I can't see any tags left un-closed so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Here are the first two lines of my XSD which I think are pretty standard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Line 791 (referenced in the error message) is simply 
`</xs:schema>`

Answer (score 3):

Well this is embarrassing. Despite stating that "I can't see any tags left un-closed" I just found one and have now solved my own problem.

I had to try copying my schema into a different XML editor in order to get a more helpful error message. I pasted my schema here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_xml_editor.htm and the error message actually identified the line containing the error.